# Can't segue selected UITableViewCells information Swift

Tags: ios, swift, email, swift2, segue

I'm making an app that allows the user to tap on cells to add a .Checkmark accessory to them. After they have selected their desired cells, they hit done and it lets them email somebody of their choosing the selected items on their list. What I can't figure out though, is how to segue the information stating what items need to be listed in the email.

this is my segue:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "emailSegue") {
        let seg = segue.destinationViewController as! emailViewController;

        seg.toPass = ??
    }
```

and this is the .Checkmark VC:
[image: .Checkmark VC]
which needs to send which cells have the .Checkmark accessory enabled to this VC:
[image]

As requested by Nirav here are the cellForRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath functions:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell: InstrumentTableCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? InstrumentTableCell

       checked = Array(count:recipies.count, repeatedValue:false)
        cell.configurateTheCell(recipies[indexPath.row])

        if !checked[indexPath.row] {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        } else if checked[indexPath.row] {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        }

        return cell
    }
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
                cell.accessoryType = .None
                checked[indexPath.row] = false
            } else {
                cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
                checked[indexPath.row] = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put your code of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @Nirav there you go :)

Comment: @zach2161 did you try my solution below?

Comment: @rigdonmr yea, I tried it but it but where and how should I make the infoToPass variable?

Comment: You have info about selected cells in your checked array, just use in and find data in recipies array with appropriate indexPaths

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!)

if (segue.identifier == "emailSegue") {
    let seg = segue.destinationViewController as! emailViewController;

    seg.toPass = cell.infoToPass
}
```

Comment: where and how do you want me to make the infoToPass variable?

Comment: The destination VC should have member variables for each variable you want to pass. I don't know what variables you want to pass so I just used a generic name "infoToPass" as an example. If you wanted to pass, say, the label's text you would do `seg.instrumentName = cell.label.text`, assuming you made a String member variable in your destinationVC called "instrumentName". Make sense?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on method you use to make cells selected. If checkmark indicates cell selected state you may get selected cells as `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows`. But be careful, indexPathsForSelectedRows reset every time you call `[tableView reloadData]`. 
As another way you could keep info about selected objects in separate array and use it in your `prepareForSegue` function. In that case you could use following code for your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath function`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSObject *dataObject = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];
    if ([self.selectedObjects containsObject:dataObject]) {
        [self.selectedObjects removeObject:dataObject];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else {
        [self.selectedObjects addObject:selectedObjects];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

And then just pass `seg.toPass = self.selectedObjects;`

Comment: prepareForSegue fires before didSelectRowAtIndexPath, this will not work.

Comment: @rigdonmr prepareForSegue fires when user hits done button. didSelectRowAyIndexPath - when user hits row. I can't understand your comment, why prepareForSegue should fire before?